# How to set the color gradient of a progress bar programmatically?

Tags: android, css, progress-bar, gradient

I made some progress bars like you can see in this picture:

[image: progress bars]

I've been using gradients to make the progress bars more appealing, but I want to use color zones (e.g. 30% full is green, 65% full is yellow, 85% full is orange, 95+% full is red).

I've seen posts how to change the color, but I would like to change the gradient itself, so I need to pass the startColor, the centerColor and the endColor.

Is there a way how I can do this?

This is what my progress bar looks like in the xml:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/proteinProgressBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_states" />
```

And this is what the progressbar_states drawable looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#b7b7b5"
                android:centerColor="#e5e5e3"
                android:endColor="#FFF" />

            <!--<gradient-->
                <!--android:startColor="#777"-->
                <!--android:centerColor="#CCC"-->
                <!--android:endColor="#FFF" />-->

            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom">
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#32A6FF"
                    android:centerColor="#0090FF"
                    android:endColor="#3232FF" />
                <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just putting this here if anyone else ever needs this.

I just made a seperate XML with the gradients for each colorzone and then I just added some code to apply that XML to the correct progressbar.

```
Drawable draw = getDrawable(R.drawable.progressbar_states_red); // Example for red gradient
pb.setProgressDrawable(draw);
```

Comment: Where is the drawable code, if you can post the xml will be helpful.